# How to uninstall Rust that was installed via rustup?

Tags: rust, rustup

I installed Rust on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine through

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
```

as can be seen on the [Installation Page](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/install.html).

How do I now uninstall Rust?

Answer (score 286, accepted):

To uninstall `rustc`, `rustup` and `cargo` from my Ubuntu 16.04 installation, I did:

```
rustup self uninstall
```

and it worked.

Comment: This also removes all installed rust programs in `$HOME/.cargo/bin`. Basically it deletes the whole `$HOME/.cargo` folder.

Comment: This doesn't work on my arch Linux Arm, `error: self-uninstall is disabled for this build of rustup`, so you'll have to use package manager

Comment: @0xB00B I mean, the problem goes away if you used a package manager to install rustup in the first place. Uninstalling a package installed via a package manager is trivial. It's a problem if you didn't; lots of distros don't package rustup in a package manager, in which case, self-uninstall is the only way to remove it, because the installation was most likely via the shell file

Comment: @Zoe stands with Ukraine it wasn't available through package manger in my case.

Answer (score 46):

If you pay attention to the message you get while installing, you will find the command you are looking for. It's `rustup self uninstall`.

[image: Rust uninstall command]

Comment: My installation command doesn't show me this.

Comment: @ShipluMokaddim I don't remember this screen only when tried to skip interactive part. In one cloud IDE i've got error that "/dev/tty" device not found. Looked into installer script and found that error is related to one question during installation (typical install and something else). Script also contains comment that "-y" argument (as I remember) will skip interactive part and run typical installation. On local devices I've seen it both in windows and linux. Probably you skiped something :D

Comment: @RyoidenshiAokigahara I solved it 3 weeks ago. Don't remember now how. But I think your comment has a good point.

Answer (score 24):

As for Linux based operating systems, the following command can be used:

```
rustup self uninstall
```

this will remove all the Rust Compiler, Tool Chains and Data including `rustc` and `cargo`
If you're one window this should wok, but you have to remove C++ build tools manually if you want to remove it as well, though I would never recommend.

Comment: Works on Mac OS

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without manually deleting the old rust binaries by uninstalling cargo and then auto-removing its now un-needed dependencies:

```sh
sudo apt remove cargo
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: Not sure how this would work if Rust was installed via `rustup`. This implies both that you're running a Debian-based distro, and that it was installed via `apt`.